# Text justifies to left when it's long, but justifies to right when it's short

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the provided layout picture (`VScode`) justifies to `left when it's long`, but justifies to `right when it's short`. What could be the issue? I just `need left text to be aligned to left and right text to be aligned to right`.

**Error:** It `does not show any errors` in the debug window or not showing any layout overflows in the layout window.

```
return Column(
         
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
              visible: true,
              child: Container(
                   

                  width: widget.c1Width + widget.columnGap + widget.c2Width,
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                     
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      width: widget.c1Width,
                      child: Text(widget.r1C1, style: defualtParahTextStyle),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: widget.columnGap,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      width: widget.c2Width,
                      child: Text(
                        widget.r1C2,
                        style: defualtParahTextStyle,
                      ),
                    )
                  ])
                  
                  ))
        ]);
```

[image]

Comment: This problem is due to the width of the container. You need to use expand and flex instead of fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkymp.jpg)

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class column extends StatefulWidget {
  const column({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _columnState createState() => _columnState();
}

class _columnState extends State<column> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child:
                      Text('FeedBack \nGiven ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Text(
                    'YES',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text('Feedback', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Text(
                    'Customer Feedback \ngiven and logged\nin the Department A \nFolder,77',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check the above code, The problem might be due to the different widths you have assigned to the containers.